# Snowflake - ERROR [HY000] [Snowflake][Snowflake] (4)

Tags: odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

ERROR [HY000] [Snowflake][Snowflake] (4)

We are running ODBC on a Windows 10 computer. I have posted an image of the error messages below. We are also NOT using a proxy server.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1M8hm.png)

Comment: Can that same computer reach the Snowflake UI?  Have you run SnowCD to check on networking issues from that computer?

Comment: Maybe your PC is behind a corporate proxy server. Can you ask your helpdesk to open firewall to snowflakecomputing.com server.

Answer (score 2):

You are connecting from behind a Proxy server, the name of which the driver is not able to resolve.
Try giving the IP address of the proxy server. Check
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-parameters.html#connecting-through-a-proxy-server
for deatails on how to connect.

Answer (score 1):

1. get the latest odbc driver
2. Change registry setting in windows to set ssl_default=true,
3. https_proxy environment variable with proxy serve:port
4. finally you would have to allow all the url that is emanating from that server to internet. There will be url's to snowflake computing and s3 aws urls while you invoke odbc different from web UI for querying.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it was solved by taking out "https://" from the beginning, so that it will be treated as a server as opposed to a URL.

Answer (score 0):

Some systems have proxy settings in their environment; this is not documented on the odbc description on the Snowflake website.
So, if the other solution don't work, check this out.